# iOS/objective c - Two column layout with dynamically added rows

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the best way to create two column layout with dynamically added rows in iOS/objective c?
I mean to create two column with text like this:

```
111111 text1
       text1
       text1
222222 text2
       text2
333333 text3
...
```

EDIT:
I'm going to specify my problem. I've created the ViewController in Storyboard and added background etc. Inside ViewController (in soryboard) I put a TableView. Now I'm trying to make the data that I downloaded from database to fit the template above. My question is how to make it to look that way?

Comment: Would you know how many lines each text is in advance, or would it have to be calculated on the fly?

Comment: Text is downloaded from database and it is simply wrapped to match the size of the screen, so we don't know how many lines it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a standard cell with style `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`then you can leave the left label empty where required. This is the best if your model is based on right column. Making a multiline label on the right is suitable but more difficult as you should calculate the cell height. With iOS8 this should be simpler if you're not tied to iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

create a UITableViewController. 
The cell needs to be built from 2 UILabels - 1 with 1 line and the other with multi line.

[image]